# File ID that doesn't change upon rename

Tags: files

I am trying to write a system utility script that will run as a cron job and capture file system statistics and environment settings in order to track as many changes as possible.

Consider the following timeline

```
T0: there is a file /dir/fileX.txt
T1: job runs and captures every file and its stats (permissions, size, checksum etc), including /dir/fileX.txt
T2: mv /dir/fileX.txt /dir/fileY.txt
T3: job runs again and recaptures the file system.  But all it can tell is that fileX.txt was deleted and fileY.txt created
```

Is there some file ID that won't change if I rename the file that I can key all the files by rather than the name?  That way, at T1 I would key the file but that ID and not the name and the file name would be just another attribute.  At T3, I will be able to tell it is the same file but the name changed because the ID remains the same.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like using inodes is what you are looking for. Referencing files based on their inode is a good way to get around some common file name issues (for example trying to delete a file that was named "test*" which would normally make rm balk), and in your particular case should allow you to reference the object.

Comment: the combination of st_dev + st_ino + st_birthtim (on systems that have it) should make it reliable. Otherwise, you could have issues if inode numbers are reused.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer I would give you is run a md5sum on the file and store the results.

After I remember an [old article](http://www.filesystems.org/docs/nc-checksum-tr/nc-checksum.html) about filesystem with checksum.
Following that concept there is an experimental option with [ext4 filesystems](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Metadata_Checksums).

There's a [report of 2013](http://nerdbynature.de/s9y/?325) that defines this feature of ext4 experimental but always better than Btrfs. The author made a script to overcame those stability problems that generate a checksum for each file and store it as and extended attribute. You find script and instruction in the report.

Maybe one of this solutions can be suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds like you need a customized host based intrusion detection system.

Have a look at some of them to check whether you can compile or configure it the way you like it to behave.

Some names: `samhain` `tripwire` `aide`